# #1052 - Column 'status' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
repeats.id,user_id,deposit_id,repeat_time,made_time,rebeat,status,created_at,updated_at
FROM repeats
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = repeats.user_id
```

I am trying to merge two tables; users and repeats, but it is giving following error.

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT repeats.id
,user_id
,deposit_id
,repeat_time
,made_time
,rebeat
,status
,created_at
,updated_at
FROM repeats
INNER JOIN users 
ON users.id = repeats.id 
LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'status' in field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: Is the field `status` in the `repeats` table, `users` table, or both?  That's what your query is asking

Comment: Always qualify all your columns, just like you did with id. Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. Oh, and if it matters, rebeat isn't really a word - unless the Urban Dictionary is your main lexical reference.

Answer (score 4):

Both your `repeats` and `users` tables seem to have a `status` column. You need to fully qualify the column in your query. E.g.:

```
SELECT     repeats.id,
           user_id,
           deposit_id,
           repeat_time,
           made_time,
           rebeat,
           repeats.status, -- Or users.status, depending on what you need
           created_at,
           updated_at
FROM       repeats
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = repeats.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, you should also qualify the column names.  Another good practice is to use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.

I don't know what your data looks like, but the query would be something like:

```
SELECT r.id, r.user_id, r.deposit_id, r.repeat_time, r.made_time, r.rebeat,
       u.status, u.created_at, u.updated_at
FROM repeats r INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = r.user_id;
```

This is just a guess.  You have to correctly qualify the names.